# Remove element and insert its text into parent element in the same place with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am writing a script to copy the content of an element to the parent element, and delete the element. The element and the parent element have the same class. For example:

Before the script runs:

```
<span class='SomeClass'>  
    Some
    <span class='SomeClass'>
        Copied
    </span>
    Text
</span>
```

After:

```
<span class='SomeClass'>  
    SomeCopiedText
</span>
```

Below is my code. The text of element which is inside ("Copied") ends up on the end of line, not between "Some" and "Text". How can I fix it?

---

```js
if ($('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').length > 0) {
  $('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').each(function(index, event) {
    $(this).parent().append($(this).html());
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Some
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>
```

Comment: Im curious, what kind of situation would you use this solution? Genuine question seems like an interesting idea.

Comment: Use `insertBefore` instead of `append`…

Comment: Are you really wanting no whitespace between the different text elements? In other words, are you really wanting `SomeCopiedText`, or is having whitespace between each portion what you desire: `Some Copied Text`. Are you wanting it in one `#text` node as would be generated with the HTML you are showing? Or, are the multiple `#text` nodes which the jQuery solutions provide acceptable?

Comment: If what you really want is `SomeCopiedText`, you are going to need to be more specific as to what you want to happen in more complex cases. For instance, do you want all whitespace removed? For instance, if we have `<span class='SomeClass'>This <span>is a test.</span></span>`, do you want that to end up as `<span class='SomeClass'>Thisis a test.</span>`, or `<span class='SomeClass'>Thisisatest.</span>`?

Comment: Wrt. my above comments: Basically, your text description is inconsistent with what you have displayed in your code. Further, it's also unclear if what you desire is to search for every occurrence of *any* class that contains an element with the same class (i.e. search for *all* such classes), or if you are wanting to search for only *one specific class* (i.e.search for *only* `SomeClass`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of removing the original `<span>` in its entirety, you can use [`contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [`unwrap()`](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) to strip the opening and closing tags.

Using this method, the `$.each` and `if` are unnecessary.

```js
$('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').contents().unwrap();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Some
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>

<br><br>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Another
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

See .replaceWith() method http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

```js
if ($('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').length > 0) {
  $('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').replaceWith(function() {
    return $(this).text()
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Some
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [jQuery replaceWith](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
var a = $('.SomeClass > .SomeClass');

a.replaceWith(a.text());
```

`replaceWith` will replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed

[EXAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/tagjmryw/)

Comment: Try not to use Fiddles on SO, use the built in code tester instead. Fiddles can be removed at any point from JSFiddle so this example may not exist later down the line.

Answer (score 1):

All of these answers use jQuery. Here's one with only native JS. Use

```
parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace(child.outerHTML, child.innerHTML);
```

Here is a fully functional recursive example that filters out duplicate classes in the child.

```js
/**
 * @function mergeHierarchy
 * @param {HTMLElement} parent - The root element to start merging under
 * @return {undefined}
 */
function mergeHierarchy(parent) {
  var parentClasses = parent.className.split(' ');
  parentClasses.sort(); // for comparing
  
  // only merge hierarchy if parent has any children
  if (parent.children.length == 0) return;
  
  // iterate over children
  for (var i=0; i<parent.children.length; i++) {
    var child = parent.children[i];
    // recurse if child has children
    if (child.children.length > 0) mergeHierarchy(child);
 
    var childClasses = child.className.split(' ');
    childClasses.sort();  // for comparing
    // if parent classes differ from child classes, then move onto the next child (after removing any duplicated classes)
    if (childClasses.length != parentClasses.length || !childClasses.every(function(item,i) { return item === parentClasses[i];} )) {
      // remove duplicate classes from child (if any)
      for (var c=0; c<childClasses.length; c++) {
        if (parentClasses.indexOf(childClasses[c]) > -1) childClasses.splice(c, 1);
      }
      child.className = childClasses.join(' ');
      continue;
    }
    // remove child from DOM and insert innerHTML into parentf
    parent.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML.replace(child.outerHTML, child.innerHTML);
  }
}

mergeHierarchy(document.querySelector('.SomeClass'));
console.log(document.querySelector('.SomeClass').innerHTML);
```

```css
.SomeClass {
  color: red;
}
.SomeOtherClass {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<span class='SomeClass'>  
    Some
    <span class='SomeClass'>
        Copied
        <div class='SomeClass SomeOtherClass'>
          (Moved) 
        </div>
    </span>
    Text
</span>
```

Please note that, since strings are immutable in JavaScript, reseting the `innerHTML` will replace any child elements with new ones, which may interfere with DOM access.

Answer (score 0):

just change the method html(), which will return the HTML code, use text() which will basically return the similar to element.innerText in Vanilla

```js
if ($('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').length > 0) {
  $('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').each(function(index, event) {
    //$(this).parent().append($(this).html());
    $(this).parent().append($(this).text());
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Some
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>
```

```js
if ($('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').length > 0) {
  $('.SomeClass > .SomeClass').each(function(index, event) {
    $(this).parent().append($(this).text());
    $(this).remove();
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="SomeClass">
  Some
  <span class="SomeClass">
    Copied
  </span>
  Text
</span>
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes Yoda, I have just noticed it. Thanks for spotting it out. 
There's a great solution up there anyway so the best option is definitely to use unwrap()